# Typescript index signature any - only works with `any`?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface and a class :

```
export interface State {
    arr : any[];
}


export const INITIAL_STATE: State = {
    arr: []
};
```

This compiles.

Now I'm chaning the Interface to be like :

```
export interface State {
    arr : any[];
    [key: string]: any
}
```

And the class to be like :

```
export const INITIAL_STATE: State = {
    arr: []    ,
    'a':2
};
```

- Still compiles.

But now - If I want to be stricter in : `[key: string]: any` ---> `[key: string]: number` :

In other words :

```
export interface State {
    arr : any[];
    [key: string]: number
}


export const INITIAL_STATE: State = {
    arr: []    ,
    'a':2
};
```

I get an error :

> Error:(7, 14) TS2322: Type '{ arr: undefined[]; 'a': number;
>   }' is not assignable to type 'State'.   Property 'arr' is
>   incompatible with index signature.
>       Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.

**Question:**

Why is that ?
I don't understand the logic behind this restriction.
What can I do to resolve it ?

Comment: As soon as you have a string or number index signature, all explicit members must also conform to that index signature. In your case everything has to be a string. This is to provide safety, but you can support number and string index by using `[key: string]: string | number;`

Comment: @Kokodoko to tell you the truth - I don't understand And I don't see any potential problem  . Would you mind posting an answer please ?

Comment: I bet thats because js objects should either have no dynamic properties, or they are used as a hashmap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following interface:

```
export interface State {
    arr : any[];
    [key: string]: number
}
```

gives me the following error without even creating an object:

> Property 'arr' of type 'any[]' is not assignable to string index type
>   'number'

This is because once you define `[key: string]: number`, TypeScript thinks all properties should be strings that map to a number. So you can't have an array unless you do:

```
export interface State {
    [key: string]: number | any[]
}
```

Note that the reason the following interface worked:

```
export interface State {
    arr : any[];
    [key: string]: any
}
```

is that `[key: string]: any` tells TypeScript "map a string to anything", in other words, "turn off type checking for each string property". That is why you can have `arr : any[];` without error.

Comment: _once you define [key: string]: number, TypeScript thinks all properties should be strings that map to a number_ ---- bad design